# Tooltip descriptions hidden beneath buttons and tables

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts, z-index

I want to add two buttons and a table to my highcharts pie chart. However when I do so, the tooltip popups get hidden underneath them.

How do I ensure that the table and buttons appear correctly but are also in the background when the tooltips (and export menu) pop up over them?

**Table and Buttons**

```
​<div style="z-index: 1; position:absolute; margin-top:50px; margin-left: 25px; font-size: 10px;"  data-toggle="buttons-radio" >
<button id="all"  type="button">All</button>
<button id="refresh" type="button" >Refresh</button>

</div>
 <table style="background-color: white; position:absolute; z-index: 1; margin-left: 400px; margin-top:70px;  width:20%; font-size: 12px;">
 <th>Output</th>
 <tr></tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Total X</strong></td>
    <td id="total" align="right">900</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Total Y</strong></td>
    <td id="renew" align="right">450</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2uf8e3xu/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to format the tooltip with HTML and CSS

```
tooltip: {
    // remove the original tooltip format
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0)",
    borderWidth: 0,
    borderRadius: 0,
    shadow: false,
    useHTML: true,
    // set the new tooltip format
    formatter: function () {
            return '<div style="border: 1px solid ' + this.point.color + '; padding: 3px;">'+this.series.name + '<br /><span style="color: ' + this.point.color + '">'+this.point.name +'</span>&nbsp;<b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.y, 2) + '</b>% of total</div>'
        }
}
```

with this css

```
.highcharts-container {
    position: inherit !important;
}
.highcharts-tooltip {
    z-index: 9998;
}
.highcharts-tooltip div {
    background-color:white;
    opacity:1;
    z-index:9999!important;
}
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davcs86/2uf8e3xu/4/)

Comment: Is there a way to ensure that the `datalabels` don't have the same issue? That they don't get covered by the third party additions?